# Must declare the scalar variable '@connection' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc, scalar

Below is the code for which am getting

> must declare scalar variable @connection

error. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please guide

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connection = Drpconn.SelectedItem.Text;
    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Sqltesting;UID=user1;PWD=test@123;Integrated Security=no;"))
    {

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO TblConfigure(Connection,Server,DbName,UserID,Password,Connection_Name,Port,Service_ID) VALUES (@Connection, @Server , @DbName,@UserID,@Password,@ConnectionName,@Port,@ServiceID)", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Connection", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", TxtServer.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DbName", DrpDbName.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", TxtUsr.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TxtPass.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectionName", Txtconnname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Port", TxtPort.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceID", TxtService.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    } // closes the connection 
    Response.Redirect("LoginPL.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Rewrite your commandtext to _INSERT INTO (.....) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)_ Odbc doesn't support named parameters

Comment: Read docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx, it should use placeholder "?" instead of using name parameters.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you should [stop using AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite your command text to follow the guidelines for [ODBC parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx). With this provider you cannot supply the command text with embedded NAMED placeholders for your parameters.
You provide this text with just a question mark for the parameter.

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for
>   ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or
>   to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these
>   cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder

Also when you add the parameters to the command Parameters collection you should provide them in the exact order expected by the INSERT fields. (But this is already correct in your current code)

```
  string cmdText = @"INTO TblConfigure
            (Connection,Server,DbName,UserID,
             Password,Connection_Name,Port,Service_ID) 
             VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, con))
  {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Connection", connection);
        .....
```

A final note. Beware of AddWithValue. It is an handy shortcut, but in certain circumstances it bites you. See [Can we stop using AddWithValueAlready?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)